# module version different between what's in yarn.lock and package.json

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg

I have the following content in yarn.lock file:

```
"@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb@^3.42.0":
  version "3.145.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/-/client-dynamodb-3.145.0.tgz#2a358e9cbb1176370488cc229d319934a6003d93"
  integrity sha512-dvy1kRTKVBiHPVrZU8aYFaHMjfoJCQ71FrhWfk5lHhLylSkRSuiffVx026Dh18b3Ob6L8N17HRAYzGV3ogAZfA==
  dependencies:
```

and the following in package.json:

```
      "dependencies": {
        "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.42.0",
}
```

This is after I did a `yarn install`. Why it's `3.145.0` in yarn.lock but it's `3.42.0` in package.json which is what I wanted.

I tried the following with no luck

1. delete node_modules and `yarn install`.
2. `yarn cache clean` and step 1 above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why it's `3.145.0` in yarn.lock but it's `3.42.0` in package.json which is what I wanted.

The package.json has `^3.42.0`, meaning any version of `3.x.y` that's greater than `3.42.0`, which includes `3.145.0`.

If you want to lock this older version: `yarn add @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb@3.42.0`